# Back4App delete associated objects script. Similar to AWS lambda

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

I have an `Employee` class and `Salary` class.

Salary class has a pointer to `Employee` class. `Employee` does not have salaries pointers. But I can extend if needed.

When I remove `Employee` record I would like to remove associated `Salary` with it. Is this possible to do via some Back4App script or function?

Or there is just a way to do it via client code. I understand that I can create a query to remove Salary where employee is needed pointer:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Salary")
query.whereKey("employee", equalTo: pfEmployeeObjectReference)

query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
//... skip cycle here
object.deleteEventually()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use-case, I recommend using the afterDelete Trigger of Employee class. To read more about triggers visit the following link:
https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#afterdelete

So your after delete trigger code should look something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("Employee", (request) => {
  //This is the deleted object      
  var deletedObject = request.object
  
  //Fetching the Salary object associated with the Employee object
  var salaryObj = await deletedObject.fetch("pointer_to_salary")

  //Deleting the salary object
  await salaryObj.destroy({useMasterKey:true});

});
```

Comment: thanks this what I am trying to do. Do I need to add this code on the Web4App? or you provided swift code?

Comment: You need to add this using cloud code. Follow this link to know more check out the following link: 
https://www.back4app.com/docs/get-started/cloud-functions